# AutoHotKey: My hotkeys don't work in combination with other modifier keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I'm trying to use AutoHotKey to emulate my [KBC Poker keyboard](http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8166/6992975668_7cfc7e8176_b.jpg) on the notebook keyboard, I want use the <kbd>RWin</kbd> key as function key, so for example, <kbd>RWin</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> would be *left*, <kbd>RWin</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd> would be *up*, etc. I have this script configured in AHK:

```
RWin & w::Send {Up}
RWin & a::Send {Left}
RWin & s::Send {Down}
RWin & d::Send {Right}
```

It works in the sense that I can use <kbd>RWin</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>/<kbd>a</kbd>/<kbd>s</kbd>/<kbd>d</kbd> to move the cursor around, however what does not work is to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>RWin</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> to select text.

Another example is the F4 key, my mapping:

```
RWin & 4::Send {F4}
```

So I would expect <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>RWin</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> to close the current window (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> behavior), but it doesn't.

I want to somehow enable the modifier keys to work with my hot keys *without* specifying each and every possible combination. How can I do that?

Comment: Put an asterisk in front of each hotkey: `*RWin & 4::`. The other requirement (with ALT + F4) is rather inconsistent. How do you expect a hotkey like `Alt + RWin + 4` to "ignore" the `RWin + 4`, but let the `Alt` trickle through? You can either have all hotkeys sent with `~` or none.

Comment: That syntax gives me an error. Example: `*RWin & d::Send {Right}`, `Error: Invalid hotkey.`

Comment: I suggest this little "hack" then: [click](http://pastebin.com/5LawkJrT).

Comment: I tried this script, but the result is the same: The cursor does move, so {Right} is triggered, but the text is not selected, so Shift is ignored.

Comment: Again, please refer to my first comment. You'll have to do some extra coding if you want to let the extra modifier "trickle through". I only wanted to show you how you can get extra modifiers to trigger hotkeys in the first place.

Comment: The problem is not that the extra modifiers prevent the defined action from happening (they don't in my case), the problem is that the modifiers are completely ignored, or, as you call it, *not trickle through*. For example if I use my hotkey RWin + d for *right* in combination with SHIFT, then I want to select text to the right. Currently the cursor only moves right and does not select. So yeah, I want all modifiers to trickle through. That's what my whole question is about.

Comment: Yes, consuming each modifier is the normal behaviour in AHK (contrary to the `~` precursor, which will let every pressed key trickle through). As I said, to change that default behaviour, you need to code it.

Comment: I thought I was already "coding" ;)

Comment: Sure, and now you need to code some more ;]

Comment: I would check if you use unicode. AHk only parse ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't necessarily answer your question, but I thought it may help you out a bit. It is basically an elaborate example of MCL's link above.

I use a function that enables me to use <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> as a cursor movement modifier.  It works for the very basics of moving the cursor but also allows for a modifier to be executed and <kbd>Alt</kbd> to be used for text highlighting. Hope this helps!

```
; Simple Movement
CapsLock & h::CapsNav("Left")
CapsLock & j::CapsNav("Down")
CapsLock & k::CapsNav("Up")
CapsLock & l::CapsNav("Right")

; Start of line or End of line
CapsLock & n::CapsNav("Home")
CapsLock & p::CapsNav("End")

; Word jump
CapsLock & .::CapsNav("Right", "!")
CapsLock & m::CapsNav("Left", "!")

CapsNav(action, initmod = "", mod = "+")
{
    If ! GetKeyState("alt")
        Send % initmod "{" action "}"
    Else
        Send % mod . initmod "{" action "}"
    SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff
}
```